# Why second example on MSDN for `lock` keyword works properly with Monitor.Wait?

Tags: c#

In threading tutorial in MSDN, 
in example number 2 -> Here's [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample2synchronizing)
i have problem with understanding how this program run well,
In the ReadFromCell there is a lock block and in the block they are using Monitor.Wait - waiting for the Monitor.Pulse in the WriteToCell method but the call to Monitor.Pulse is also in lock block of the same instance so how we will get to this call, somone can explain?

Sorry for my english, i tried to make it more specific, hope it more understandable.
Anyway i received an answer to the question, thanks.

Comment: It works as documented in the documentation. If you ahve a specific problem, ask, but "how does it work" is too broad. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Monitor.Wait releases the lock until it is pulsed.

Comment: @TomTom OP did specify what they do not understand, what's the problem?

Comment: That he never said hat exactly he does not understand. I am not going to go through a documented example line by line because someone is too lazy to even tell me what he does not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember from the top of my mind whether there is a good explanation anywhere; but from experience this is the reason most people have problems with Monitor:

There are two queues associated with an object:

The ready queue: the thread is waiting for the lock object to be released in order to obtain it and run.
The wait queue: the thread is waiting for a pulse (or wait timeout).

Threads in either queue do not have the lock, and only threads that have the lock can call `Wait` or `Pulse`.

So the "life-cycle" is:

1. Upon calling `Monitor.Enter()` (or reaching the start of `lock` block): The thread enters the ready queue and waits in line for the lock to become free. It needs to wait for all other threads in the queue before it to obtain the lock and release it (or to leave the queue) before it can obtain the lock and continue running.
2. The thread obtains the lock. It is now the only thread running inside the `lock` block.
3. The thread calls `Wait()`. It releases the lock and joins the wait queue. It must now wait for all other threads in the 'Wait()' pool to be pulsed (or time out).
4. After some time our original thread is at the head of the wait queue. Another thread obtains the lock and calls `Pulse` this moves our original thread to the end of the ready queue.
5. The thread that called `Pulse` releases the lock. This allows the thread at the head of the ready queue to obtain it.
6. After some time our thread again reaches the head of the ready queue and re-obtains the lock. It now continues to run the command after `Wait()`
7. Our thread calls `Monitor.Exit` (or reaches the end of the `lock` block) and releases the lock.

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs of [Monitor.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdc87f8y(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Releases the lock on an object and blocks the current thread** until it reacquires the lock. If the specified time-out interval elapses, the thread enters the ready queue.

I don't know what can I add to that. This is exactly why the code works..

Hm.. one (obvious) thing worth noting (maybe) is that the lock will be reacquired when Monitor.Pulse is called, but it will not happen immediatelly. As the lock was released, so other threads may hold it now, so after the Pulse'ing the current sleeping thread will have to wait until someone releases the lock.